# Azure Cost Management API is not returning the Blob location

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-rest-api, cost-management

I have a PowerShell script that calls the Microsoft Azure API for cost management.

I first call:

> [https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/enrollmentAccounts/*****5/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/generateCostDetailsReport?api-version=2023-08-01"](https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/enrollmentAccounts/*****5/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/generateCostDetailsReport?api-version=2023-08-01%22)

This returns a 202 as expected:

> StatusCode        : 202
> StatusDescription : Accepted
> Content           : {}
> RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
> Pragma: no-cache

I then extract the header location and poll until I get a 200

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           :           {"id":"/providers/Microsoft.Billing/enrollmentAccounts/7****5/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/costDetail   sOperationResults/ca4f*******-d8bff1dbf7c2","name":"ca4f85f****-d8bff1...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                Pragma: no-cache
                Vary: Accept-Encoding
                session-id: ae0a1b9b-2d21********6136a55bcb
                x-ms-request-id: d2f**********85-8d7f54a02fb7
                x-ms-correlation-request-id: 23b94e5d...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Pragma, no-cache], [Vary, Accept-Encoding], [session-id, ae0a1b9b-2d21-4088-82f4-      106136a55bcb], [x-ms-request-id, d2f0ab18-e34c-*****4a02fb7]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 935
```

```
The problem is that I'm expecting a blob location to be returned but it isn't. 
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. 

The blob location should be in the Manifest section 
i.e ......Manifest.blobs.blobLink


I 


I've tried different versions of the API be all return the same. 
I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this Official [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage?view=rest-cost-management-2023-03-01&tabs=HTTP#enrollmentaccountquery-legacy) the Azure Cost management API with scope set to **`enrollmentAccounts`** does not contain any blob location in the request. If you want to retrieve the cost of the blob resource, You need to use:-

```
'/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}'
```

where **resourceGroupName** is the name of your resource group containing your blob.

***My sample Powershell script that calls the Cost management API:-***

```
$AppId = "xxxxxx-6d26a31435cb"
$AppSecret = "xxxxhhZ~bY."
$TokenURI = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx95/oauth2/token"
$Resource = "https://management.core.windows.net/"

$BodyRequest = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$AppId&client_secret=$AppSecret&resource=$Resource"

$AccessToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $TokenURI -Body $BodyRequest -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$RequestURI = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7/resourceGroups/siliconstrg909-rg/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2023-03-01"

$Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $AccessToken.access_token
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Updated request body structure
$UsageRequestBody = @{
    type = "Usage"
    timeframe = "MonthToDate"
    dataset = @{
        granularity = "Daily"
        aggregation = @{
            totalCost = @{
                name = "PreTaxCost"
                function = "Sum"
            }
        }
        grouping = @(
            @{
                type = "Dimension"
                name = "ResourceGroup"
            }
        )
    }
}

# Convert the updated payload to JSON
$UsageRequestBodyJson = $UsageRequestBody | ConvertTo-Json

# Make the request using Invoke-RestMethod
$UsageRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestURI -Headers $Headers -Body $UsageRequestBodyJson -ContentType 'application/json'

# Output the response
$UsageRequest.properties.rows
# Check for pagination
while ($UsageRequest.properties.nextLink) {
    $NextLink = $UsageRequest.properties.nextLink
    $UsageRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $NextLink -Headers $Headers -Method Get
    $UsageRequest.properties.rows
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

In your **enrollmentAccounts Rest API**, Try to add **ResourceGroup name in value** that contains your blob:-

```
$AppId = "xxxxxx26a31435cb"
$AppSecret = "xxxxxxxZ~bY."
$TokenURI = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/83xxxxxx92395/oauth2/token"
$Resource = "https://management.core.windows.net/"

$BodyRequest = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$AppId&client_secret=$AppSecret&resource=$Resource"

$AccessToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $TokenURI -Body $BodyRequest -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$RequestURI = "https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/enrollmentAccounts/*****5/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/generateCostDetailsReport?api-version=2023-08-01"

$Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $AccessToken.access_token
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Updated request body structure
$UsageRequestBody = @{
    type = "Usage"
    timeframe = "MonthToDate"
    dataset = @{
        granularity = "Daily"
        filter = @{
            and = @(
                @{
                    or = @(
                        @{
                            dimensions = @{
                                name = "ResourceLocation"
                                operator = "In"
                                values = @("East US", "West Europe")
                            }
                        },
                        @{
                            tags = @{
                                name = "Environment"
                                operator = "In"
                                values = @("UAT", "Prod")
                            }
                        }
                    )
                },
                @{
                    dimensions = @{
                        name = "ResourceGroup"
                        operator = "In"
                        values = @("YourSampleResourceGroupName")  # Replace this with your actual resource group name
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

# Convert the updated payload to JSON
$UsageRequestBodyJson = $UsageRequestBody | ConvertTo-Json

# Make the request using Invoke-RestMethod
$UsageRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestURI -Headers $Headers -Body $UsageRequestBodyJson -ContentType 'application/json'

# Output the response
$UsageRequest
# Check for pagination
while ($UsageRequest.properties.nextLink) {
    $NextLink = $UsageRequest.properties.nextLink
    $UsageRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $NextLink -Headers $Headers -Method Get
    $UsageRequest
}
```

Also, There's a separate [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties?tabs=microsoft-entra-id#request) dedicated to Azure Blob Storage, You can try calling the [Azure blob Powershell command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-11.0.0) to retrieve the blob properties like below:-

```
# Connect to Azure account and set the desired subscription
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId xxxxxxxab9
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 'xxxxxxcb2a7'

# Get the storage account context
$ctx = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "valleyrg87" -Name "siliconstorage678"

# Check if the context is retrieved properly
$ctx


# Get the storage account context
$ctx = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "valleyrg87" -Name "siliconstorage678"

# Check if the context is retrieved properly
$ctx

# If context is retrieved successfully, proceed to get blob properties
if ($ctx) {
    # Get the blob reference
    $blob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Blob "hello_world.py" -Container "data" -Context $ctx.Context

    # Check if the blob is retrieved successfully
    $blob

    # If the blob is retrieved successfully, get blob properties
    if ($blob) {
        $properties = $blob.ICloudBlob.Properties
        $properties
    } else {
        Write-Host "Blob not found or there was an issue retrieving the blob."
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Storage account not found"
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your response.
Looking at your code I realised I had a difference. I was using Invoke-Webrequest when I was looking for the blob location when it should have been Invoke-RestMethod.
Making this single change returns the required Blob Location details.
id        : /providers/Microsoft.Billing/enrollmentAccounts/7***5/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/costDetailsOperationResults/9bb4efc1-*****e5f-0afdaec988b8
name      : 9bb4efc1-4b4e-49******daec988b8
status    : Completed
manifest  : @{manifestVersion=2022-05-01; dataFormat=Csv; byteCount=46517627; blobCount=1; compressData=False; requestContext=; **blobs=System.Object[]}**
validTill : 2023-12-06T23:39:58.9165023

Many thanks